# Run SQL function for each returned record

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a sql function that calculate some numbers and returns 1 to 4 records for each run, the function gets clientID (int).

I have a query that selects ALL clients. I want that on each client the function will run and will return its values. something like that:

```
ClientID | FunctionReturnValue
   1               1.1
   1               2.1
   1               1.9
   1               1.3
   2               1.9
   3               1.3
```

Any ideas?

Comment: When you say "function". You mean table valued function? If so why is this tagged "stored-procedures"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just use the function in your `select`:

For example if you have a scalar function.

```
select
    ClientId,
    dbo.YourFunction(ClientId) as FunctionReturnValue
from YourTable
```

If you have a Table Value Function try this:

```
select
    ClientId,
    FunctionReturnValue
from YourTable
cross apply dbo.YourFunction(YourTable.ClientId)
```

Comment: You are assuming a scalar UDF which seems unlikely from the description. Scalar UDFs return a single value not `1 to 4 records`